# Is the following an example of one point compactification?

Tags: general-topology

How do I prove that the space $X = \left\{\frac 1n : n \in \mathbb Z\right\}$ is not compact but $X \cup \{0\}$ is compact ?

Comment: ... when viewed as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $X\cup\{0\}$ is a one-point compactification of $X$. Let $Y=X\cup\{0\}$.

HINT: Showing that $X$ is not compact is easy: an infinite cover by pairwise disjoint open sets has no finite subcover, and there are lots of those. Showing that $Y$ is compact is also very straightforward: if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $Y$, there is some $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $0\in U_0$. What can you say about the set $Y\setminus U_0$?

Comment: ok ok.. I got it. Y∖U will contain finitely many elements of X, which can be covered by finitely many elements of the covering. Right ? Thanx a lot !

Comment: @Sharabh: Yep, you’ve got it; you’re welcome!

Comment: I have one more confusion. In the definition it says that the elements of the covering are subsets of X itself. So what are the elements of the covering of X. Precisely what are the open subsets of X ? (Pardon if its a foolish question, I am just a beginner actualy)

Comment: @Sharabh: $X$ has the discrete topology: **every** subset of $X$ is open. Thus, each $\left\{\frac1n\right\}$ is an open set, and the collection of these is an open cover of $X$ with no proper subcover at all.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Sharabh: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Each point in $X$ is open as $\left\{\frac1n\right\}=\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n-1}\right)\cap X.$ So $X$ is an infinite discrete space. To see that  $X^*=X\cup\{0\}$ is compact let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $X^*$ and consider an open set around $0.$

The convergent sequence $X^*$ is actually homeomorphic to the one-point-compactification $\Bbb N^*$ of $\Bbb N.$ Note that each convergent sequence $(x_n)_n$ in a space $X$ together with its limit $x$ is continuous image of $\Bbb N^*.$